# How to use jquery noConflict()?

Tags: jquery

I got 2 jquery plugins both need to be called on $(document).ready, but i figured out that when i call both on ready, the second doesn't work.

I've tried to use jquery noConflict() but i didn't worked.

someone could explain it for me?

thanks.

Comment: `noConflict` has nothing to do with running 2 different plugins on docready... Your plugin might be clashing with each other

Comment: Could you show your code? I would expect you'd be able to make the necessary calls to initialize both plugins during ready.

Comment: This, most probably, happens because of two things. 1. Your plugins are dependent to different versions of jQuery. 2. Your functions might be conflicting because they have functions with the same name. So, while you are at it, tell us the plugins you use and their versions.

Answer (score 2):

[`jQuery.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) is for conflicting JavaScript libraries (both using `$` as a name, for example) - not conflicting plugins. All it does is change `$` back to whatever it was before jQuery was added.

Comment: It will also remove `jQuery` if you pass `true`.

Comment: @icktoofay: Yup, and if you ever need that, you're doing something seriously wrong :)